# Format Code to Output New Rows for Number Expansion

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code

```
    Sub ExpandRanges()

    Dim X As Long, CG As Variant, Rng As Range, Cell As Range
    Dim Series As String, CommaGroups() As String, DashGroups() As String
    Set Rng = Range(Range("H2"), Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
    For Each Cell In Rng
    CommaGroups = Split(Cell, ",")
    For Each CG In CommaGroups
    DashGroups = Split(CG, "-")
    For X = DashGroups(0) To DashGroups(UBound(DashGroups))
    Series = Series & ", " & X
    Next
    Next
    Cell.Offset(, 1).Value = Mid(Series, 3)
    Series = ""
    Next

    End Sub
```

That gives me and output of:

[image: img1]

Can anyone reformat the code to where it creates a new row for each number that is expanded from the range? Rather than expanding them out into a new column to where I have to separate them again manually.

I would like for it to look like this (referring to the first range)

[image: img2]

Comment: Can you add an example of how you want the result to look?

Comment: @BennoGrimm I've added a snapshot! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

EDIT: Fixed

```
Sub ExpandRanges()

Dim X As Long, CG As Variant, Rng As Range, Cell As Range
Dim Series As String, CommaGroups() As String, DashGroups() As String
Dim j As Long, lastrow As Long, newrow as Long

j = 0
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

newrow = InputBox("What is the row number of your new range?")

Set Rng = Range(Range("H" & newrow), Range("H" & lastrow))

For Each Cell In Rng

    CommaGroups = Split(Cell, ",")

    For Each CG In CommaGroups

        DashGroups = Split(CG, "-")

        For X = DashGroups(0) To DashGroups(UBound(DashGroups))
            If j = 0 Then j = Split(Cell.Address, "$")(2)

            Rows(j + 1 & ":" & j + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            Cells(j, 9).Value = X

            Range("C" & j + 1 & ":H" & j + 1).Value = Range("C" & j & ":H" & j).Value

            j = j + 1
        Next

    Next

Next

'Band-aid solution
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Range("C" & lastrow & ":H" & lastrow).ClearContents

End Sub
```

[image: img1]

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I entered this code and it is making new rows, but as soon as it does it stops working and basically just freezes, do you think this is because I am running it on a wide range of numbers?

Comment: right now, about 18 rows of ranges, but I plan to add more, I think it's getting jammed up because it has so many ranges to go through, because it is working when I just do it with one range, but then freezes when I do it with 18 ranges

Comment: @nabusafe Try letting it run - inserting rows can be taxing for Excel - if you're not getting an error message then it's probably just running, to be honest.

Comment: hmmm.. it seems to only be freezing once another range is added. If I am only asking it to expand one range it runs fine, but once I add another range that's when it freezes and won't run anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: Ahh so you're appending a new range onto the bottom of the already expanded range? It's going to freeze because it's starting from the top and now it's doing a multitude of insertions...

Comment: Yes yes I am wanting to append all the ranges that are listed underneath, do you know if there is a fix to this?

Comment: A simple solution would be to change the 2 in `Set Rng = Range(Range("H2"), Range("H" & lastrow))` to whatever the row is that you just inserted a new line of ranges on, but there might be something more dynamic you could do.

Comment: @nabusafe Try the new edited code - I think this will be your best solution, for now... no need to overcomplicate.

Comment: The only thing about that, is that with this code I am wanting to put it into a form in Access to run by the press of a button, so updating the code with the latest row every time would be inefficient is that matter. Is there a way around this to get all the ranges to append on top of each other?

Comment: Yes it is still freezing up unfortunately. Essentially with this code I am going to upload a file with number ranges, and then hopefully press a button that will run this code and append all of the expanded numbers in new rows. If that makes sense. This code is very close to doing that, I just need it to accept multiple rows

Comment: @nabusafe Like I said before, are you sure it isn't just running? Inserting rows in Excel can take quite some time - how long are you letting it run for? It is *not* going to run instantly.

Comment: No I understand that, I dont think its the issue of running because my whole excel pane will freeze up and tell me that the program is not responding. I have let it run up to 10 mins straight with no result.

Comment: Hm - what are the number ranges you're giving it? Are any of them 1-1000 or something large?

Comment: No, just the ones I have attached in the first screen grab. If I can get it to run those then I will continue to add more. What do you think the issue is?

Comment: in the code, what is the line If j = 0 Then j = Split(Cell.Address, "$")(2) referring to?

Comment: @nabusafe I realized that a lot more will have to be done to get this code to work - that `Split` line grabs the row number from the `Cell.Address`. The issue here is that we're using `lastrow` but trying to loop over a range that's ever growing. A lot of this code will have to be rewritten with a `Do/Loop`.